# Pandas: Group by unknown time period

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset with different time periods. I'd like to group it per id and per time period, but: I don't know, how long each time period is or when it even starts. The one thing I surely know: A new time period starts, when the difference between two timestamps is higher than two minutes.

Example: Here we have two time periods:

- from `05:36:07` to `05:36:42`
- from `21:54:16` to `21:54:37`

Data:

```
id,timestamp,value
00b0f3,2018-05-21 05:36:07,4
00b0f3,2018-05-21 05:36:14,6
00b0f3,2018-05-21 05:36:24,2
00b0f3,2018-05-21 05:36:40,1
00b0f3,2018-05-21 05:36:42,6
00b0f3,2018-05-21 21:54:16,3
00b0f3,2018-05-21 21:54:27,2
00b0f3,2018-05-21 21:54:30,6
00b0f3,2018-05-21 21:54:34,4
00b0f3,2018-05-21 21:54:37,9
```

This should somehow end like:

```
id,timeserie,value
00b0f3,1,19
00b0f3,2,24
```

Are there any helpers from pandas, which allow me to detect time periods by a max between time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `pd.Grouper` as follows:

```
df = df.groupby(["id",pd.Grouper(key="timestamp", freq='2min')]).sum()
```

The result would be:

```
>>> df
                            value
id     timestamp                 
00b0f3 2018-05-21 05:36:00     19
       2018-05-21 21:54:00     24
```

If you want to have `id` as a separate column you can run below code line:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

And the resulting `DataFrame` would be then:

```
>>> df
       id           timestamp  value
0  00b0f3 2018-05-21 05:36:00     19
1  00b0f3 2018-05-21 21:54:00     24
```

### Note

I pasted your data to a `csv` file and then imported it and created the `DataFrame` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("D:/tmp/data.csv")
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `cumsum` and boolean test condition with `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['id',
           (df['timestamp'].diff() > pd.Timedelta(minutes=2)).cumsum()], 
           as_index=False)['value'].sum()
```

Output:

```
       id  value
0  00b0f3     19
1  00b0f3     24
```